How to read the fully replicated data using the atlas search aggregation pipeline?
I want to read the fully replicated data using the atlas search aggregation pipeline.
But, Atlas search is not allowing me to read with concern "majority".
Error Message:
Command aggregate does not support { readConcern: { level: "majority", provenance: "clientSupplied" } } :: caused by :: Aggregation stage $search cannot run with a readConcern other than 'local'. Current readConcern: majority'.

So, How can we ensure the consistency in the search result?
I've read the documentation and understood that the $search stage is performed by the mongot service and it won't work with non-local read concern. I don't know why and how can MongoDB guarantee the consistency in search results.



Cluster tier    : Dedicated M10
Node Type       : electable
cluster         : 3 node replicaSet
Mongodb version         : 7.0.14
pymongo         : 4.10.1
writeConcern    : majority
readConcern     : majority
read preference : secondary

I have not enabled workload-isolation; So,mongot and mongod services are running in each nodes of the replicaSet cluster.
I think i need a help to understand the atlas search setup. Thanks in advance.
